# Возможно ли написать кроссплатформленый текстовый редактор не на web технологиях?

Tags: текст, редактор-текста, работа-с-текстом

Есть сайт и задача сделать мобильное/десктопное приложение для него. На сайте используется WYSIWYG для textarea (toast ui editor). Реально ли написать что-то подобное чтоб работало нативно? Или хотябы на Swift? Где вообще почитать как текст рендерится на экране? Как, например, вот такое работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И стоит ли вообще этим заморачиваться или лучше использовать WebView?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть на сторону RAID Studio FireMonkey

Comment: Чисто из опыта, когда приложение работает не точно так же как сайт, пользователей это бесит. Особенно если на сайте больше возможностей, чем в приложении. А самый простой способ сделать аналог - веб технологии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рендеринг производится по разному в зависимости от того, на каком уровне абстракции вы будете работать. К примеру, вы можете использовать программные средства операционной системы и создавать интерфейс на их основе. Именно поэтому во многих приложениях, кнопки и другие элементы очень похожи и отличаются в зависимости от версии операционной системы.

В целом скорее всего вам этих знаний будет достаточно.

Что касательно кроссплатформерности, все зависит от языка и библиотек, которые вы будете использовать. Библиотеки содержат внутри себя различный код в зависимости от платформы, на которой он будет использоваться. Однако, некоторые языки позволяют не заморачиваться об особенностях платформы и писать идентичный код для разных платформ, например Java. Она использует виртуальную машину, внутри которой как раз и преобразуется ваш код на Java в код, который подходит для платформы, в которой вы ее запустите. Но это именно особенность этого языка. Такой возможности (нативной) нет например у C#, а потому запустить приложение на нем можно будет на Windows, но не MacOS.
Так же есть языки, в которых код будет идентичный (ну или более менее идентичный), но будет запускаться на разных платформах, но тут придется собирать проект под соответствующую платыорму индивидуально. Таким языком например является C++.

Ну и собственно, стоит ли для такого приложения использовать веб?
Ну, зависит от того, сколько времени вы готовы уделить проекту, готовы ли вы заниматься обработкой кросплатформерности и заниматься правками в коде в зависимости от платформы.
Если вы готовы, то можете смело брать например тот же C++. Если хотите упростить разработку, но сделать ее нативнее, Java в помощь.
Если хотите абсолютно с этим не запариваться, то вы можете посмотреть на такие вещи как Electron или ReactNative.
Не обязательно именно его. Просто он является одним из примеров того, как можно даже на скриптовом (интерпретируемом) языке написать кросплатформерную программу, так как ваш код будет обрабатываться уже платформозависимой оберткой, которую уже написали за вас другие умные люди.

WebView не советую. С ним может быть масса проблем с обработкой ввода, так как оболочка может не предоставлять средства в достаточной мере.

Лучше такие вещи делать если у вас нет другого выбора и часть, которая будет написана таким образом будет максимально отделена от остального кода, написанного на чем то другом.

Comment: Нет желания делать очередную поделку на Электроне, в браузере и так все работает как PWA. Просто хотелось легковесное и шустрое приложение, но видимо сейчас не просто так все на жабаскрипте всё делают.

Comment: @EgoDziuba, кросплатформерное решение, которое будет работать везде и "одним файлом" по определению не может быть легковесным. Единственное что я уже предлагал, это Java, оно достаточно шустрое и для интерфейсов можно использовать тот же JavaFX. Будет и нативно, удобно и быстро.